# how to represent norm

Tags: vector, norm

I have an array A=[1 2 3 4 5]. 
    I want to take norm-1 of it, i-e 
      (1-2)+(1-3)+(1-4)+(1-5) and 
      (2-1)+(2-3)+(2-4)+(2-5) and 
      (3-1)+(3-3)+(3-4)+(3-5) and so on. 
    How can I represent this in methametical form

Comment: A) I assume from your other questions you're doing this in MATLAB, right? You should tag the question as such. B) What kind of norm are you describing? It sounds like your result from `A` would be `[-10 5 0 5 10]`. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) you could do something like this with [`linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> print(numpy.linalg.norm((a), ord=1))
15.0
```

Comment: Actually I want to write in a paper (research). I dont know how to write in methamatical form,

Comment: I am no expert but I think you may not be at the level of knowledge to *"write a paper"*, firstly you do not have the basic "research" skills (i.e. ability to google) to search how to do this extremely trivial question in mathematics... which is very well documented everywhere on the net... Secondly you come to this website do not recognize that it is not about math (you didn't look around at all, you should have realized you needed to ask on http://math.stackexchange.com/) ... Yet you post your question anyway...

Comment: I actually feel sorry for you, whatever `educational institute` you are from has somehow given you the confidence that you can pilot a aeroplane (writing a research paper) when you can't even ride a bicycle...